# Create a MS access pass-thru query to ODBC database & return all table names & field names without the data

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc

I want to create a "pass-thru" query in MS Access 2013 that will connect to a ODBC database already setup on my computer ODBC configurations.

The query should find and return all the table names related to the database, and also all the field names in each column of each table.

But, not any other data records.

I don't know the database table names and want to include all of them.

I know how to do everything except the SQL code.

The ODBC database is oracle, and my computer is Win7 32 bit.

My current SQL code is:

`SELECT * FROM *`

But this returns all the data from all the tables.  I just want to table names and table field names.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or something along those lines?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I have a question like "what data dictionary table give me the data I need"  I open the [Oracle Database Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/toc.htm), go to the index, then start looking for names that look like "likely suspects".

In your case, you'd want to

```
SELECT OWNER,
       TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME
FROM DBA_TAB_COLS
    ;
```

After you scan through the index a few times (or the contents) you start to get a feel for how names are structured and get better at guessing how the view you want might be named.

DBA_something -- all of something in the database.  Requires necessary privileges.

ALL_something -- all of something that the current user has been granted access on.  Includes his own somethings and that of others that he has privileges to see.

USER_something -- all of something actually owned by the current user.